# android accessibility service ACTION_CLICK doesn't work with window overlay

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, accessibilityservice

I am trying to click the force stop button using the accessibility service.when i find the FORCE STOP button i click it using:

```
childNodeView.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
```

this  is successful in ordinary scenario, however when I try to hide the process from the user using a window manager overlay the click doesn't work. This makes since maybe because there is a screen over the button I am trying to click, however there are several applications on the play store that have the described functionality with a window overlay

these are my window manager params:

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    oneTapProgressView = new OneTapProgressView(this);
    windowManager.addView(oneTapProgressView, params);
```

Note: I run this from a different service and not from the accessibility service

How do I perform the click with the window overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is related to the overlay type.  Specifically TYPE_PHONE. Phone overlays have special mechanisms to trap events so that users don't accidentally touch buttons with their cheek why talking on the phone.

You should try a different type.  For Android O Try:

```
TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
```

For prior operating systems you want:

```
TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

Both of these will require the following permission:

```
SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Also, the following flags may be useful if the above alone doesn't fix it:

```
FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
```

Comment: thanks it works! also thanks for the heads up on the TYPE change in O.

Comment: followup question: the accessibility works only with FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE for me. this flag cancels all the click listeners in the overlay view. Is there a way to handle click events in the overlay view with the FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE set ?

Comment: No. But it's difficult for me to recommend alternatives, because it would be confusing for me to see a scenario where the accessibility stuff is working correctly and not otherwise. Is there an app that exhibits the behavior you want on Google Play?

Comment: 1. I've made a programming mistake, actually the views in my overlay view are clickable (with setOnClickListener offcourse) 
2. there are alot of apps that have this functionality, mainly apps that tap on settings screens
3. the purpes of clicking the overlaywindow is to give the user the ability to cancel the operation of the feature if it takes too long, if the overlay window is displayed for too long not block his phone