# Android App behaves strangely with System Overlay

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

So I currently build an Android App (for API 24 and above, using Visual Studio and Xamarin, but not a Xamarin.Forms App) which displays an overlay icon if a certain app is running.
If I run the emulator within VisualStudio everything works fine, Overlay Button is clickable and everything is working like it should, even if build as RELEASE and running it through Emulator (I tested API 24 (Android 7) and upwards till 29 (Android 10))

So if I pack it to an apk and install it on a physical device (also Android 7 till Android 10, because I have multiple Tester) the overlay icon also displays, but if the user press on it, nothing happens. Its like the click is not registered anymore.

**//edit: one Major problem I have: 
Only Android devices I have is Android 6 (API 23) and Android 9 (but with a broken usb-debug thing: after I connect the device with my pc, it says: USB Debugging active, then the message disappears and again. So there is no way to debug the app on a Android device myself (main Smartphone is iPhone)**

Here is some code:

My "Main"Class is defined like this

```c#
public class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService, View.IOnTouchListener, View.IOnClickListener
```

ImageButton and View is defined globaly to access it in my class

```c#
private static ImageButton Overlay;
private static View OverlayLayout;
```

as soon as the overlay button should be displayed I fo this:

```c#
windowManager = GetSystemService(WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
OverlayLayout = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Sidebar, null, false);
Overlay = new ImageButton(this);
Overlay.Id = View.GenerateViewId();
Overlay.SetOnTouchListener(this);
Overlay.SetOnClickListener(this);
Overlay.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.app64);
WindowManagerTypes layoutFlag = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O
   ? WindowManagerTypes.ApplicationOverlay
   : WindowManagerTypes.Phone;
paramsF = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
             layoutFlag,
             WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal | WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable,
             Format.Transparent);
paramsF.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom | GravityFlags.Right;
paramsF.X = 100;
paramsF.Y = 0;
windowManager.AddView(Overlay, paramsF);
```

I heard that the WindowManagerTypes for a Overlay to be displayed are not the same if the API is 26 or greater.

in the OnCLick Event I have this:

```c#
Log.Debug("Service", "CLICK->" + v.Id);
if (v.Id == Overlay.Id)
   OpenShortInfo();
```

in the OnTouch Event I have this just to log some things:

```c#
Log.Debug("Service", "TOUCH->"+v.Id);
```

Both Debug Logs are called if I use the Emulator but not if I use physical device.

Thank you for the help and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you check whether `Log.Debug`  is called or not on a real device ?

The method is used to print logs in output window when debugging , nothing would happen when running on a real device .

Try to show AlertDialog to see if  `OnCLick` event triggered or not .

```
        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
        alert.SetTitle("Title");
        alert.SetMessage("Complex Alert");
        alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
        {
            // Ok button click task  
        });
        alert.SetButton2("CANCEL", (c, ev) => { });
        alert.Show();
```

#### Update

```
 public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        Log.Error("Click","------------------click");
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            Log.Error("OnTouch", "------------------touch");

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I added a Toast to make this. But this also did not show up which means its not triggered. But the question is: why its triggered on emulator and not on real device

Comment: Could you use button instead of imagebutton and try again ?

Comment: I will try that, on sec

Comment: same result only moveable (in my OnTouch event) but not clickable

Comment: Can you tell me what's the system version you test on simulator and real device ? Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45003285/8187800

Comment: Oh thanks i will try the refer.    If you mean OS Version, its Android 7-10 in emulators and 8,9,10 on device

Comment: So this methode explained in the refe did not work sadly

Comment: I guess the touch event blocks click event , so modify your code as below , check my update .

Comment: thanks, yes the click event was not fired because of the touch event. I do the "onclick" thing now in ontouch and checking if it was not moved.
Thanks for your help